# Combinations in C#

Tags: c#, combinations

I need to find all possibilities of a List<int>. If I will have elements: **{2,2,3}**, the result needs to be:

- { 2 }
- { 3 }
- { 2, 2 }
- { 2, 3 }

But **not { 3, 2 }**. All because it will multiply 2*3, so 3*2 is pointless.

It will not be 3 elements, like here, but e.g. 10 and more (base on what user will enter).

I was searching a lot, but I always saw "3,2" included.

(Program will return all dividers of number entered by user)
(I'm beginner in C#)

Comment: The word you are looking for is _combinations_.  Do a search for _Linq combinations_ to find some algorithms.

Comment: Can you add your code that you've tried?

Comment: Linq, Distinct will eliminate duplicate entries, you can also Take in sets of N. Then you can Aggregate,  Sum or otherwise.

Comment: @Jay but then you'd have to write logic to define `{2,3}` and `{3,2}` as "equal"

Comment: Which can be further eliminated by keeping the nodes excluded in a separate entity or and checking the input from start to the current offset for existence of both elements. E.g. using Contains or Any.

Comment: So you want to find all distinct values for the returning combinations when multiplied?  You could even do something like a hashtable that stores the product of each combination found and only add it to the result list if it isn't present in it

Comment: @Allan I don't write this yet. I'm just thinking how to resolve this problem first. Then I'll write all. It'll be small program, it's only to practice.

Comment: Yes it's only one line.